# RuntimeError with mysql2 and rails3 (bundler)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, bundler

I get this error

```
`establish_connection': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter) (RuntimeError)
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-
```

[Here](http://pastie.org/1088017) is dump of whole error and my config and gemfile.

Comment: I faced the same problem and after several analysis, i am able to successfully install the mysql2 on windows with rails3. The process i followed is given in the following blog post. http://www.kyybaventures.com/blog/installing-mysql2-gem-ruby-rails-windows Hope, it will be useful to solev the above problem. Mani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error after upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04.  This is how I fixed the problem:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
bundle
```

I think the key here is the 'native extensions' -- I suppose when I installed last, I was using a different version of mysql.

```
Installing mysql2 (0.3.11) with native extensions
```

Answer (score 101):

I was getting the same error while using rails 3.0.7 and mysql2 0.3.2.
The solution, which I found [here](http://rubyonrailsthrissur.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/error-mysql2-adapter-gem-install-activerecord-mysql2-adapter/),
is to use an older version of mysql2. Thus edit your gemfile to

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: This one fixed it for me on Ubuntu 10.04!! If using RVM, you can also use: `rvm gem install mysql2 --version=0.2.7`, and add the above line to your Gemfile.

Comment: I had this exact same issue today, going up to 3.1 and back down to 3.0.7. This was the fix.

Comment: except those versions of mysql2 have blocking issues in large sites

Comment: Same here - apparently mysql2 > 3.0 does not load the AR adapter pronto

Comment: That fixed the problem. On Ubuntu 11.04 Natty

Comment: For more enlightenment, see the following mysql2 issue on github, which says mysql 0.3.x will only work with rails 3.1 and onward: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/155

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Excellent!

Comment: Still useful for those of us still maintaining Rails 2.3 apps but who want to use mysql2 for its better UTF-8 handling. I don't think Rails < 3 works with mysql2 0.3+

Comment: Install `homebrew` if you are using mac osx and then do `brew install` mysql. After that, `bundle install` and it should work. :)

Answer (score 36):

Also need to change adapter from `mysql` to `mysql2` in database.yml as said here
[Install mysql2 gem on Snow Leopard for Rails 3 with rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297253/install-mysql2-gem-on-snow-leopard-for-rails-3-with-rvm)

From:

`development:
  adapter: mysql`

To:

`development:
  adapter: mysql2`

Answer (score 14):

Did you include the mysql2 gem in your gemfile instead of the old mysql gem, and ran bundle install afterwards?

Comment: This might help someone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3/3608756#3608756

Answer (score 6):

If you're using rvm, and possibly added mysql2 outside of rvm, try these steps:
Confirm that your Gemfile says:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

or for Rails2.x:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.11'
```

then:

```
$ cd RAILS_ROOT
$ gem uninstall mysql2

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. mysql2-0.2.11
 2. mysql2-0.3.6
 3. All versions
> 3 # select "All versions"
$ rvm gemset install mysql2
$ bundle install
```

Now rails should start properly.

Answer (score 3):

This also fixed the issue I had with:

```
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter)
```

You actually need to run: gem install mysql2 and add the gem to your config.

Comment: I was having this problem as I was installing the mysql2 gem manually. Then I used it as you said in the gemfile and ran bundle install. It loaded up, but I I got the could not connect to mysql.sock error. So I THEN ran env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql2 --version 0.2.6 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config (i am on a mac pro) and this seemed to solve my problems. Ran rails s and hey presto..Hope this helps someone else out :)

Comment: @dryprogrammers - Wich I could give you 100+, please put your comment as answer, it is VERY relevant for Ubuntu 12-10 as well.  On fully updated Ubuntu 12.10 Precise gitlab would not install. Bump. After many hours (6-8) of searching and trying many things, I tried your mac hack as a last resort. LO AND BEHOLD much as I (cough) don`t really care at all for Macs ... this did it for me now I can go to bed ... happy! :)

Answer (score 2):

just run "gem install mysql"
also add the same in gemfile and run bundle.
worked

Comment: this clued me in. I ran "sudo gem install mysql2" and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Manual gem management outside of a Gemfile is not recommended.  It is prone to dependency issues for other developers or deployment.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody still facing problem of installing mysql2 gem with rails 3 on Windows, then refer to the detailed steps of installation on -

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm a beginner at ruby, rails, and linux. So if this solution did not work, I hold no responsibility :)

**Step 1:**

```
sudo gem uninstall mysql2
```

**Step 2:**

```
sudo gem install mysql -v 0.2.7
```

Start webrick, if the same problem still appears reinstall rails.

This solution works for me.

Comment: Isn't it generally bad practice to install a gem using sudo?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me too. Upgraded to Rails 3.1.rc4 then downgraded to 3.0.3. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> as of 0.3.0, and ActiveRecord 3.1 - the ActiveRecord adapter has been
>   pulled out of this gem and into ActiveRecord itself. If you need to
>   use mysql2 with Rails versions < 3.1 make sure and specify gem
>   "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7" in your Gemfile

the missing file (`no such file to load`) can be found in the pre 0.3.0 versions of mysql2.

quoted from the [documentation of mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#activerecord)