# installing mysql2 gem errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I installed ruby and ruby gems through macport but the gem list does not include mysql2. So how would I get mysql2 gem installed inside my gem list which is inside "/opt/local/bin/gem"

Also, what is the mysql2 gem? I have mysql gem and only want to use mysql, not really sure what it means by mysql2. It gives my a mysql2 error when I try to launch webrick on an app.

UPDATE:
I ran sudo gem install mysql2 and got the following:

> Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... Successfully
>   installed mysql2-0.2.7 1 gem installed
>   Installing ri documentation for
>   mysql2-0.2.7...
>
> Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for
>   class Client not known
>
> Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for
>   class Result not known Installing RDoc
>   documentation for mysql2-0.2.7...
>
> Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for
>   class Client not known
>
> Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for
>   class Result not known

Assuming that mysql2 installed, even though the docs didn't I get the following error when I try to launch webrick in my app.

rails server:

> /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle:
>   dlopen(/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle,
>   9): Library not loaded:
>   libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
>   Referenced from:
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>   Reason: image not found -
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8
>     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in
>   `require'     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in`
>   require'     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in
>   `each'    from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in`
>   require'     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in
>   `each'    from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in`
>   require'     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:112:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/summer/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
>     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in`
>   require'     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
>     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in
>   `tap'     from
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
>     from script/rails:6:in`require'
>     from script/rails:6

Comment: You are missing libmysqlclient-dev headers try and search for that library in macports. That is what i had to install on my Ubuntu in order to install the gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, one of the differences between the two gems (mysql and mysql2) is that mysql2 works better with UTF-8. Here [is an article](http://www.rorra.com.ar/2010/07/30/rails-3-mysql-and-utf-8/) about it.

To install your mysql2 gem, just run:

```
gem install 'mysql2'
```

Comment: Please take a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115126/ruby-gem-mysql2-install-failing. Read all the answers, specially the one from Holger Just.

Comment: But from your logs, it seems that the gem got actually installed, the error is just related to the docs!

Comment: @Amokrane that doesn't help, I'm using a 32bit version processor, and I'm getting a different error.

Comment: Hmm could it be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297253/install-mysql2-gem-on-snow-leopard-for-rails-3-with-rvm ? (I remember having the same issue as well)

Comment: how do I access database.yaml file?

Comment: It's inside your app directory: config/database.yml

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform a search for remote gems that are available run the command
gem search mysql2 -r (note the -r at the end)

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

activerecord-mysql2legacydb-adapter (0.2.0)
activerecord-mysql2spatial-adapter (0.3.2)
em_mysql2_connection_pool (0.0.5)
ghazel-mysql2 (0.2.6.3)
mysql2 (0.2.7, 0.2.6 x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32-60)
mysql2_bigint (0.2.6.1)
mysql2_model (0.1.2)
mysql2mysql (0.0.2)
mysql2psql (0.1.0)
mysql2xxxx (0.0.4)

from the list of gems you should pick mysql2 and run
sudo gem install mysql2