# mysql2 gem installation on linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install a gem on linux but it is giving me an error:

```
An error occured while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11' succeeds before bundling.
```

What do I need to do now?

Answer (score 16):

Probably, it can't build mysql2 native extension.

If you're using Ubuntu 14.04 or newer, try `sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql libmysqlclient-dev`.

On older versions of Ubuntu install this: `sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev`

On OS X: `brew install mysql`

There are also similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/installing-mysql2-gem-for-rails-3), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115126/ruby-gem-mysql2-install-failing), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297253/install-mysql2-gem-on-snow-leopard-for-rails-3-with-rvm).

Comment: it is `ruby-mysql` now instead of `libmysql-ruby`

Answer (score 0):

I was using LInux 16 Cinnamon and got that error message.  I used "Resure"'s, solution sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev

then ran bundle install for project.

It worked!