# Error: Incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, utf-8

I got the error `incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT`, when the view found in the database some characters like: ñ, á, é, etc.

My enviroment is:

- Rails: 3.2.5
- Ruby: 1.9.4p194
- Database: Oracle 10g (10.2.0.1.0)

I can save this characters in the database, using Toad.

I tried to write this, in the first line of my view:

```
<% # encoding: utf-8 %>
```

In `enviroment.erb`

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

But nothing fixed this.

Please, can someone give some adviced to fixed this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the database and national character set?  `select * from v$nls_parameter where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET'`?

Comment: As suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779740/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii-8bit-and-utf-8-in-ruby-1-9 you should read about and understand character encodings. The suggested links are a good place to start.

Comment: thank @JustinCave for your answer, I gonna check this.

Comment: @AdamHawkes thanks for your comment, I'll read the link for understand this.

Comment: @JustinCave this is the sql's result:      NLS_CHARACTERSER = WE8ISO8859P1  and  NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `boot.rb`, I added this line:

```
ENV['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'
```

Whit this I solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issues, and I resolved it after hours of searching with a monkey patch.

```
    module ActiveSupport #:nodoc:
      class SafeBuffer < String

        def safe_concat(value)
          value = force_utf8_encoding(value)
          raise SafeConcatError unless html_safe?
          original_concat(value)
        end

        def concat(value)
          value = force_utf8_encoding(value)
          if !html_safe? || value.html_safe?
            super(value)
          else
            super(ERB::Util.h(value))
          end
        end

        alias << concat

        private

        def force_utf8_encoding(value)
          self.force_encoding('UTF-8').html_safe unless self.encoding.name == 'UTF-8'
          value = (value).force_encoding('UTF-8').html_safe unless value.nil? || value.encoding.name == 'UTF-8'
          value
        end
      end
    end
```